# php - json encoded jquery output

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am using the devbridge jquery autocomplete plugin to create a autocomplete search. I have been able to get it to work EXCEPT for the onSelect part.

I am returning proper JSON encoded data (see below - copied from firebug)

```
    {"query":"pa",
     "suggestions":["Acer palmatum 'Bloodgood'","Quercus palustris","Euonymous elata 'Compactus'", "Parthenocissus tricuspidata"],
     "data":[4,5,7,10]}
```

As mentioned above, everything works properly, all suggestions show up and are selectable, etc, BUT when I select an item the alert message pops up with

```
    you selected: undefined, null
```

JQUERY CODE

```
    $("#query").autocomplete({
        serviceUrl:'includes/search.php', 
        width:350,
        minChars:2,
        onSelect: function(suggestion){ alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.suggestions + ', ' + suggestion.data); }        
    });
```

AND FINALLY, PHP CODE

```
    include ("connect.inc.php");

    $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['query'])); 
    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);

    $qstring = "SELECT botanicalName, plantID FROM plants WHERE botanicalName LIKE '%$term%'";
    $result = mysql_query($qstring);

    $reply = array();
    $reply['query'] = $term;
    $reply['suggestions'] = array();
    $reply['data'] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $reply['suggestions'][]=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['botanicalName']));
        $reply['data'][]=(int)$row['plantID'];
    }

    echo json_encode($reply);
```

As always thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you the only JS part. Could you please try this;

```
$("#query").autocomplete({
        serviceUrl:'includes/search.php', 
        width:350,
        minChars:2,
        select: function(event, ui){ alert('You selected: ' + ui.item.suggestions + ', ' + ui.item.suggestions.data); }        
    });
```

Comment: browsers aren't recognizing the select function so I don't even get an alert now, I think because select isn't an autocomplete option. I tried it with the known option onSelect and still no alert at all.

Comment: I think you are using older version of jquery autocomplete